# Adding images to existing JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, base64

i have a function that retrieves me a JSON, now i would like to add an image to each entry in base64 (depending on the header which image i will add) and it has multiples levels. 
How can this be done?

This is a JSON example of what my functions already retrieves:

```
"Animals": {

      "Cat": true,

      "Dog": true,

      "Dino": {},

      "Shark": {

         "White": true,

         "Regular": true

      },

   }
```

And I would like to remove the `true` and instead of it, replace it with an image (base64 format) that would depend on the tag.

the finished JSON would look something like:

```
"Animals": {

      "Cat": YWJjMTIzIT8kKiYoKSctPUB+abc123!?$*&()'-=@~,

      "Dog": QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==,

     ....
```

Comment: Please add more details about what you want to do, for example a starting json string and a "finished" json string with your image data, and how your are generating the image data in the first place.  Please add this information in an EDIT TO YOUR QUESTION AND NOT A COMMENT.  thanks

Comment: Done. look at my edits

Comment: Please add an example of the finished json with your image data, like i asked for.

Comment: You can't "add an image" to JSON as it's just a string.  So i suspect what you want to do is add some data about an image, eg it's url or something.  So, we need to know what you mean by "image", and what you actually want to write into the json for the image.

Comment: sorry, i don't have that much experience in posting questions. Getting better, though. Added some info to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is an answer which addresses your question as it stands.  I suspect that it's not very helpful.  It's still not clear what you're actually having difficulty with.

Let's say i have a valid JSON string (Note: yours isn't valid: i had to remove a comma and wrap the whole thing in curly braces to make it valid)

```
mystring = "{\"Animals\": { \"Cat\": true, \"Dog\": true, \"Dino\": {}, \"Shark\": { \"White\": true, \"Regular\": true } }}"
```

I convert it to a ruby hash with JSON.parse:

```
myhash = JSON.parse(string)
=> {"Animals"=>{"Cat"=>true, "Shark"=>{"Regular"=>true, "White"=>true}, "Dog"=>true, "Dino"=>{}}
```

I change the value of Cat to the desired value.  Note that i have no idea whatsoever if this value is correct, or how it was generated, it's just copied from your question.

```
myhash["Animals"]["Cat"] = "YWJjMTIzIT8kKiYoKSctPUB+abc123!?$*&()'-=@~"
=> "YWJjMTIzIT8kKiYoKSctPUB+abc123!?$*&()'-=@~"
```

I convert it back to JSON.

```
myhash.to_json
=> "{\"Animals\":{\"Cat\":\"YWJjMTIzIT8kKiYoKSctPUB+abc123!?$*&()'-=@~\",\"Shark\":{\"Regular\":true,\"White\":true},\"Dog\":true,\"Dino\":{}}}"
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfect as an example of what i needed.